# Pivot table with identical IDs but different intermediate table values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

The Laravel docs say this:

> You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs:
>   $user->roles()->sync([1 => ['notes' => true], 2, 3]);

I am wondering if it is possible to do something like this:

> $user->roles()->sync([1 => ['notes' => true], 1 => ['notes' => false]]);

I am doing the above currently in a slightly different way, and Laravel appears to be simply overwriting the 1st entry in the pivot table with the 2nd entry, so the pivot table looks like this:

```
user    role  notes
1       1     false
```

Is there a way to use sync() so that it will save both values in the pivot table, so it would look like this?

```
user    role  notes
1       1     true
1       1     false
```

If sync() cannot do this for me, is there a different way of creating the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use attach() instead like this:

```
$user->roles()->attach(1, ['notes' => true]);
$user->roles()->attach(1, ['notes' => false]);
```

and if you want to erase previous values, you can use sync() with an empty array before doing the above like this:

```
$user->roles()->sync([]);
$user->roles()->attach(1, ['notes' => true]);
$user->roles()->attach(1, ['notes' => false]);
```

and then the result you will have will be the desired result in the DB:

```
user    role  notes
1       1     true
1       1     false
```